# Prohibit download of files (direct link) if an specific session is not null (.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, event-handling

I need to block users for downloading some PDF files if a session is not null and if the file is marked as private (checked trough DB table)

I have tryed global.ascx solution but I can't access in none of this events AcquireRequestState, PreRequestHandlerExecute the session state..

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: What do u mean by session is not null ?

Comment: So you're saying that during the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null? [That event gets called a lot, so the session will be null _sometimes_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088530/session-is-null-in-acquirerequeststate-when-loading-virtual-directory-name-in-br)

Comment: Have you tried writing a custom handler to manage PDF delivery? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123961/filehandler-in-asp-net/19124733#19124733

Comment: Hi  @nikhilvartak the session is started in an application... So if the session is not null and have a value, then you will be able to download the file. If you receive the link to download the pdf you won't be able to download the file unitl you enter into a web page that assign a value to the session...

Comment: Hi @MikeSmithDev the session is not null.. I get an error that Session State is not available all the time the event is called...

Comment: @MikeSmithDev will check that custom Handler, thanks!.... Does this will work even when the link is called outside the web page?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I did try the code that you suggested, but i'm getting that context.Session is always null, so I can't get any session... Any Ideas?

Comment: @ricardo_escovar yes it will work for any link to a PDF.

Comment: @ricardo_escovar check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14181556/1810243

Comment: Thank you very much @MikeSmithDev Everything is working now!!..